# iOS - Address Sanitizer and Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer compiler error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

When we try to compile our C++ iOS game app with these two profilers in Xcode, we're getting the following linker error.

```
Ditto /Users/Max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TowerDuel-dsejjkbvgengpngaqrfokeoaquvx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TowerDuel-mobile.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib /Users/Max/Documents/XcodeWorkspace/TowerDuelWorkspace/TowerDuel/lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib
    cd /Users/Max/Documents/XcodeWorkspace/TowerDuelWorkspace/TowerDuel/proj.ios_mac
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/Max/Documents/XcodeWorkspace/TowerDuelWorkspace/TowerDuel/lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib /Users/Max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TowerDuel-dsejjkbvgengpngaqrfokeoaquvx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TowerDuel-mobile.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib

ditto: can't get real path for source '/Users/Max/Documents/XcodeWorkspace/TowerDuelWorkspace/TowerDuel/lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib'
Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

It seems like it's trying to use some iOS 8.1 library, even though our deployment target is iOS 9.

How can we fix this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the issue also happens when only using ONE of these at the same time.

Comment: Not your problem, but; you can't (AFAIK) use both at the same time - you have to use each on its own.

Comment: It also happens when only using one of them.